# Launcher or an App for Restricted Access which one is better?

Tags: android, security

Hi I am planning to create an android app which is similar to the
[Samsung Kids Mode- parental control](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x6Dq3sr4y6M)
If you can see the link I gave, it is obvious that the app overrides the Home button when inside the app... I wanted to create a similar app for friends mode and stranger mode and should not come out of the app when home button is pressed... is it possible without root access?? My ultimate aim is to not come out of the app without entering a password, So if it is just an app after android 4.0 it just comes to the home screen when home button is pressed, So If I create a custom launcher and make it default even after pressing home button it will be inside the app if I am right, but is there any way I can do the same without a launcher

Also to avoid the phone number suggestions which happens when we dial parts of numbers in the dialler, should the phone be rooted to so it or is it possible without that?

Thanks in advance to everyone for taking time to read this, hoping a positive solution